# Why I do not get all the image data in an Indy HTTP connection FireMonkey?

Tags: bitmap, firemonkey, http-get

I am developing a mobile application in FireMonkey and I want to take a photo with smartphone camera and store it in my Firebird database.

I'm having several problems passing the image data through the HTTP connection which I use, since not I get all the image data in the server and I think there is a maximum size for parameter in the GET request of the HTTP connection or similar something.

This is the code I use:

**SAVE IMAGE DATA IN STREAM. PASS STREAM TO JSON**

```
stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  image.Bitmap.SaveToStream(stream);
  stream.Position := 0;
  jsonPhoto := TJSONArray.Create;
  try
    jsonPhoto := TDBXJSONTools.StreamToJSON(stream, 0, stream.Size);
  finally
    //jsonPhoto.Free;
  end;
finally
  stream.Free;
end;
```

The size of jsonPhoto.toString, where the image data are, is **2368 bytes**.

**SEND DATA TO SERVER BY HTTP CONNECTION**

```
try
  result := IdHTTP1.Get(TIdURI.PathEncode('http://'+MyDirIP+':8080/DATABASE_NAME?USERNO='+userNum+'&BUILDINGNO='+jsonBuildNo+'&BUILDINGNAME='+jsonBuildName+'&OBJECTNO='+jsonObjNo+'&OBJECTNAME='+jsonObjName+'&PHOTO='+jsonPhoto.ToString+'&NOTE='+memo_Notes.Lines.Text));
except
  on E: Exception do begin
     ShowMessage('Error connection: '+E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

The content of jsonPhoto.toString I get on the server has not all data who I sent, by this reason, I think that there is a parameter size by default in the HTTP connection. Moreover, I have tested that the size of image data received is **999 bytes**. In the other parameters I get all the information without problem.

Moreover, when I get data in server, Should I save it in database like a json text or like a stream?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `GET` request. `GET` has size limitations, depending on server settings, because all parameters are send in URL.

Use `POST` instead of `GET`

> Should I save it in database like a json text or like a stream?

It depends on how you will continue to use the data. For ease of access to the data as image - it is better to store as a stream.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly which was happening!! Use POST solved my connection problem, but my limitation in size was due to I was limiting it without I knew it. Thanks, I took a long time with this matter. Sorry for delay in my answer.